# Is there a way for me to get more than 1,000 entries from a fetch command in React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I am new to React and am using fetch to get data in the form of a JSON from an online website. The website's file has 6 million rows and my [network tab when I hit f12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B590P.png) only gets 1,000 from it. Is there a way for me to get more than 1,000 rows from the fetch command? Or a way for me to read a CSV file and search through all of the rows?

Here is my code in case:

```
state = { items: []};
componentDidMount(){
    this.getItems();
}
getItems(){
    fetch('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/5uac-w243.json?')
    .then(results => results.json())
    .then(results => this.setState({items: results}));
}
```

Comment: That depends entirely on the details of that specific API, React and fetch are irrelevant here. Check their docs, look for the keyword pagination.

Comment: fetch will get whatever your server API send you and rows count is depend on your API in back-end not front-end issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's not fetch that is limiting. It's just that `GET https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/5uac-w243.json` returns an array of only 1000 objects. If a request to that url would return 6 million records, fetch would receive 6 million records. Though you probably don't want to render that.